# UWP App: Sign in to a Microsoft account

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, uwp, windows-10-universal

I would like to use roaming app data. This only works if the user logs into her devices using a Microsoft account. See [Roaming App Data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465094.aspx).

However, a lot Win10 users use still a local account. Now I would like to provide a “Sign in” feature like the Microsoft Weather App provides in the menu (last entry). If you select “Sign in” or “Sign out” a view is shown with:

> Signing in lets you sync your references and favorites across devices
>   and helps us to personalize your experience.

That is exactly what I would like to integrate into my app.
When I search for this then I find just articles about using the [Web Account Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/web-account-manager) with the Microsoft Accounts (MSA) provider. But this is not the same and does not help to activate roaming for local user accounts.

How can I implement the same “Sign in” feature in my App like the Microsoft Weather App has?

Comment: I tested the Weather APP across devices using local accounts, it won't roam either.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The "Sign in" feature in the MSN Weather App and some other MS Apps seems to be useless when a local account is used.